# creating a 3rd party application server using rails to send gcm push notifications

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to rails and i wanted to know whether i would be able to change my existing server in rails to a 3rd party application server by adding the gem **gcm_on_rails** . I have installed the gem in this assumption and have pushed a message to the gcm server using the code in the console

```
   device = Gcm::Device.create(:registration_id =>"APA91bGJSaiKkCm_h9w8prWsL_inTMPs8pmCme8dcLpW0_2AKbny4bTXpx823cCfJLDJmO3_ihiww1ZVK0iqToAlPWKFWcBSraGRw6KNB1PsLYJJWvRZJ3bMP0")
   notification = Gcm::Notification.new
   notification.device = device
   configatron.gcm_on_rails.delivery_format = 'json'
   notification.collapse_key = "updates_available"
   notification.delay_while_idle = true
   notification.data = {:registration_ids => ["APA91bGJSaiKkCm_h9w8prWsL_inTMPs8pmCme8dcLpW0_2AKbny4bTXpx823cCfJLDJmO3_ihiww1ZVK0iqToAlPWKFWcBSraGRw6KNB1PsLYJJWvRZJ3bMP0"], :data => {:message_text => "Get on cloud nine"}}
   notification.save
   Gcm::Notification.send_notifications
```

and i am getting the response as

```
response = {:code=>200, :message=>nil}
```

but in the documentation of the above gem itself its said that even if the `message=>nil` is shown the message might have been send!

I am assuming that the message was send have also created an android application having the aforesaid registerid but also i am not getting any notification

A help on this scenario would be greatly appreciated

thank you

Comment: Have you found out the problem why you did not get any notification?

Answer (score 0):

I used the gem '[gcm](https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm)'. I found it better to send data to my android app via GCM. It also has near real time response. Just set up a Rails server and add a script in the main directory with the following code:

```
require 'gcm'
api_key = 'your-gcm-api-key'
gcm = GCM.new(api_key)
registration_ids= ["client_reg_id1","client_reg_id2"] # an array of reg ids of app clients
options = {"label"=>"data"}
response = gcm.send_notification(registration_ids, options)
```

start the rails server and then run this script using `ruby -rubygems script.rb` from the command line and you are done.